# Есть ли ресурсы для запроса обзоров (review) кода написанного на русском языке?

Tags: обсуждение, инспекция-кода

"StackOverflow на русском" и "Toster.ru" не позволяют этого делать согласно правилам и своей политике. Так же и англоязычные ресурсы не подходят, по тому что код преимущественно на русском языке. Причём не просто отправка участка кода а ссылку на репозиторий и/или на конкретный Pull Request.

Comment: А вопросы о рекомендации сторонних ресурсов, "согласно [правилам и своей политике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" тут считаются оффтопиком.

Comment: Чтоб вы знали что искать, вы (лично вы) фактически ищете себе ментора.

Comment: Нуууу катастрофа даже вопрос негде задать, издевательство какое то.

Comment: Ещё вопрос, кого над кем :) Общественной (т. е. кому-то кроме вас) пользы от этого приблизительно ноль. Так что да, найти желающих может быть непросто.

Comment: Ментор не подходит по тому что ему нужно платить, а я хотел бы участия на собственном энтузиазме и желании помочь проекту, так как это делают в open source. Или есть бесплатные менторы? Мне кажется таким нито не захочет заниматься бесплатно.

Comment: @D-side, ну если конечный продукт open source и использование бесплатно, он может помочь не только мне, так что польза есть и обществу

Comment: @D-side, в смысле кого над кем? Вы хотите сказать что это Я издеваюсь над людьми прося о помощи. Ну ни чего себе. Я только что понял. Так меня мало кто расстраивал. Абалдеть я прошу помощи при этом издеваюсь над кем то, вы в своём уме?

Comment: Проблему вы обнаружили совершенно правильно. И open source проект притягивает энтузиастов только когда он способен убедить в своей пользе. Поэтому вашей задачей будет скорее создать интересующий людей проект, и явно указать, что горячо приветствуете активный code review. Способов же раскрутки open-soruce проектов много. Но важно дойти до момента, когда вам будет что показать. Потому что один раз плохо себя показав, можно здорово навредить шансам на успех при следующих попытках.

Comment: К сожалению, да, я очень даже в своём уме. Как вы и сами заметили, таким вряд ли кто-то захочет заниматься бесплатно на этом этапе. А просить людей работать бесплатно -- да, издевательство, смежного калибра. Я не пытаюсь вас подколоть или обидеть, я объясняю ситуацию в наиболее выразительной/понятной, но, возможно, жестковатой форме.

Comment: Я не прошу работать бесплатно, я прошу помочь. Вы понимаете чувства человека который просит помощи, а ему говорят что он издеватеся? отчаяние, горе, одиночество. Думаю не стоит вам так вести себя.

Comment: Это одно и то же. Просьба приложить усилия на пользу третьего лица без немедленной компенсации. Да, я понимаю чувства человека в такой ситуации, списываю их на наивность и прямо на это указываю. И как человек, к которому с подобными просьбами обращаются регулярно (лично), я как-нибудь сам решу, как себя вести :)

Comment: Вы, правда, неверно поняли. Просьбой вы ничуть не издеваетесь. Просто на неё вряд ли кто-то ответит, поскольку не хочет издевательств над собой уже в процессе, потому что просите вы немалого. Вот.

Comment: @D-side: я совершенно бесплатно опубликовал ответы на тысячи вопросов. Вот несколько моих ответов с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a23044%20%5bcode-review%5d

Comment: @jfs важно различать небольшие изолированные часто встречающиеся у широкого круга лиц вопросы или непонятые моменты и инспекцию pull request'ов конкретного проекта от одного конкретного человека (пока проект не привлечёт существенного внимания, чтобы появились и другие участники). Так что ваше примечание к вопросу не относится.

Comment: @D-side нет, это вы не поняли. Нажмите на ссылки и почитайте. Вопросы с меткой инспекция-кода к отдельной категории относятся. Прочтите описание метки.

Comment: @jfs я уже давно читал описание метки (и не наблюдаю существенных изменений с тех пор) и [сам отвечал на несколько таких вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A181100+%5Bcode-review%5D). И всё ещё не наблюдаю ни единого повода сомневаться в вышеизложенном.

Comment: @D-side с чем вы тогда не согласны? Единственная проблема, что человек хочет ссылку вместо кода приводить, что нельзя (вопрос должен быть самодостаточным). Но если код в самом вопросе, то в чём проблема? (предполагая, что и другие требования из описания метки инспекция-кода выполнены)

Comment: @jfs если не в ссылках, то в объёме кода, а значит в запредельно высоком пороге вовлечения отвечающих, что **у нас** вынудит закрывать такие вопросы как "слишком общий", а в других местах может вызвать отзывы ещё пожёстче моих или вообще ничего (мёртвую тишину). Напоминаю, что закрываются вопросы в большой степени для их же авторов, чтобы они могли поправить вопрос так, чтобы сильно повысить шансы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: @D-side, "сам решу, как себя вести". Тогда знайте сейчас вы обидели человека и внесли отрицательную пользу, в том числе для общества по тому что к вам обращаются регулярно как вы сами указали. Более того, я подробно прочитал первую ссылку с правилами которую вы прислали и там нет пункта про внешние ресурсы, а есть тот к которому относится мой вопрос, а именно в части "Какие вопросы можно задавать?" последний пункт "к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике...". На практике возникшая проблема "незнание ресурса для запросов обзора русскоязычного кода в репозиториях".

Comment: @jfs, спасибо что поняли меня

Comment: @D-side, "Уточняю: автор просит ревью pull request'ов" Я даже ещё ничего особо не просил, я просто спросил о наличии ресурса

Comment: @Димка ваша обида меня нисколько не задевает. Меня интересует, чтобы вы осознали суть проблемы и избежали лишних сложностей и разочарований от неё в дальнейшем. Вы можете проигнорировать то, что я сказал, и разбиться об закрывашки или тишину на других ресурсах. Это ваше право. Со мной нередко бывает, что на меня обижаются за замечание или критику, а потом приходят со словами "чёрт, а ты был прав". Я в ответ не обижаюсь. А что касается этого конкретного вопроса, на него просто нет однозначно верного ответа. Ваш ответ тоже таковым не является.

Comment: Я даже под пытками никогда не скажу что вы правы

Comment: Если бы вы хотели что бы я избежал сложностей, ответили бы просто, как ответил я

Comment: Меня не интересует, скажете ли вы что я прав или нет, как и что вы обо мне думаете, так что не тратьте нервы на личные нападки. Я детально изложил проблему и свой опыт её решения. Право от всего этого отказаться и понабивать шишек остаётся за вами. Я ранее убедился, что "простые ответы" людей обычно не удовлетворяют, т. к. не содержат раздела "а почему так?". Этого раздела нет и в вашем ответе. И вам нечего в нём написать, т. к. он фактически неверен.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72504/discussion-on-question-by--------review-).

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент таких ресурсов нету.
Но возможно привести конкретный участок кода соблюдая правила:
[Справка > Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
[Описание метки [инспекция-кода]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info)

Обычно в уже популярные или интересные проекты энтузиасты находятся сами. По этому стоит заинтересовать людей уже более-менее готовым и интересным проектом, либо раскручивать его.